# Can't find installed feature

Tags: feature-upgrade, solution

Years ago I developed a feature for our OnPremise Farm and today I need to update it.

It is listed in the site collection features of the root web `https://portal/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site`, active and it works fine where it is used, but when I try to look it up using `GET-SPSolution` or `GET-SPFeature` it isn't listed anywhere.

Need help.

Thanks.

**Edit**:
The Feature/Solution isn't listed in the `CentralAdministration->Manage farm features`, nor in the `CentralAdministration->Manage farm solutions`

**Edit**:
In the page `https://portal/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site` the feature is listed, by clicking on deactivate in the url I was able to get the ID. I figured out that I had to use `Get-SPFeature -Identity thefeatureId -site http://portal`, but I'm still not able to find it in the Central Administration

**Edit**:
Thanks to Robert Lindgren I figured out it is a Sansbox Solution.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a sandboxed solution? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg615450(v%3Doffice.14)

Comment: Only features with `Scope=Farm` show up in Central Admin.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to **Central Administration** > System Settings > Manage farm
  solution > You will find it here.
- Update Solution with [SharePoint PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/update-spsolution?view=sharepoint-ps): `Update-SPsolution`

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: As I already wrote, Get-SPSolution does not list my solution.

Comment: So this solution is not in your environment (you can validate if you find it in the Manage fam solutions) If you need to install use first Add-SPSolution after this Install-SPSolution

Comment: ...as I already wrote, the solultion is used and works fine in a sitecollection

Comment: so it needs to be in Central Administration. Maybe different name? otherwise if you need update it, use Update-SPSolution

Comment: Well, I cannot TRY to update something in production that is present but somehow also missing. If something go wrong...

Comment: You havent testing environment?

Comment: Yes, but it is not 1:1 with production. It is rather a dev env.

Comment: can you try create new test site collection, list all enabled SPsolutions, enable your solution if you can see it in Manage Solutions on Site, again list all enabled SPSolutions and compare the outputs. Is here difference?

Comment: or try to install this solution on the dev environment and try figure it out here